# Material design autocomplete - Down arrow key event

Tags: material-design, angular-material

I am using `md-autocomplete` in AngularJS Material Design. I want to show all the items available when I `click` the <kbd>Down</kbd> key. Is there an event available for that in `md-autocomplete`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-keyup` and `ng-keydown` with md-autocomplete. That might help.